# Why did my RC-XD short circuit in Black Ops?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I used my RC-XD, but after 10 seconds of looking for an enemy to blow up my car became unresponsive and started fizzing.

I thinks it's the equipement thing (can't think of the name off hand), but if it is how was it used and why did it affect my car everywhere I tried to drive it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An RC-XD can be disabled by stuns and flash grenades much like a turret claymore, or other piece of equipment can.  When your car is disabled it fizzes and becomes uncontrollable for a short period of time, this is temporary unless the car is destroyed while disabled.

You can do this to other RC-XD's by hitting it with a flash or stun explosion.